# I have this: mysite.com/profile.php?user=Mike but i want this: mysite.com/Mike

Tags: php, html

My php script parse the user information from My MySQL data base and shows it when a get or post action Is made. As you can see the format must be ?user=Name but i want to make it like Facebook do; /Mike, its anyway to do this whitout making a folder for each user? Thanks!

Comment: This is not an issue you could solve with PHP. This needs to be handled by your web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod_rewrite should solve your problem. Here's a guide to getting started:
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite